# Does it talk about any Instances of not using sarcasm in conversation in the Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, words, torts-damages, conversation

Does the Talmud ever mention any caution against using sarcasm in conversation to avoid hurting another with words?

Comment: What makes you think that it might?

Comment: I mean the Talmud is full of sarcasm so I would say it’s fine

Comment: @CuriousYid Not if it hurts someone's feelings.

Comment: How would that be different than other forms of hurting someone's feelings with words? @N.T.

Comment: אמר ליה: רחמנא ליצלן מהאי דעתא - אדרבה, רחמנא ליצלן מדעתא דידך

Comment: דמהדר ליה רבי ללוי כמדומה אני שאין לו מוח בקדקדו

Comment: בני רוֹכֵל תקברם אִמָּן

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.9b.5?lang=he&with=all

Comment: @TamirEvan It wouldn't be.